# In guake, why only the first tab is transparent?

Tags: guake

In guake, if I press "F12", I get the semi-transparent HUD-like terminal as expected. But if I then press "ctrl-shift-t" to open another tab, the new tab will not be transparent any more. Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes definitely its a bug.
i just removed and installed it again and now its working fine.
after installing it again, when you open it for the first time, the first window completely opaque. its nothing. just go to the preferences>>appearance tab and then re-adjust the transparency option scroll bar to some other value. thats it. its done.

hope it works.

Comment: Changing the transparency setting did the trick. I'm not sure whether re-installation changed anything.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Guake in Ubunut 13.04 using:

```
sudo apt-get install guake
```

It installed version 0.4.4, and all tabs are transparent.  See images below.

I think it might be something wrong with your setup.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Un accepted?  Its been almost 4 months, and I still say its not a bug....  I have demonstrated that in my answer :)

Comment: Nope. You have only demonstrated that it does work in your configuration. Lack of proof rather than proof of lack. Also, thanks to abbas, my guake now works correctly.

Comment: OK.  But I don't think its a bug.  A bug is a problem with the software, regardless of what configuration you have.  If it works on a particular setup, but not another, its related to hardware.  Any ways, good luck.

Comment: Good luck with your definition. So if a program incorrectly fails to zero a memory allocated with `malloc`, and works fine in some configurations (because memory from certain OS'es is initialized for security reasons), but not others (yes, I have seen cases like this), then this is not a bug? Please. If this is not a bug (although it has been reported by another user as well), how do you call it? A feature?